# DirectX Large Models > 64k C++

Tags: c++, directx, index-buffer

My DirectX11 C++ Engine uses uint16_t (short) for the vertex index buffer and all was working well.

I've evolved the models I use and now they have grown with over 64k indexes.

I've changed all references to my index buffer from short to uint32_t and the render was broken.

My variable defines are:

```
ID3D11Buffer        *IndexBuffer;     //DirectX Index Buffer
vector<int32_t>     primitiveIndices; //Vector array of indicies formally
```

I finally changed the line

```
Context->IASetIndexBuffer(IndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0);
```

to

```
Context->IASetIndexBuffer(IndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT, 0);
```

This was done to allow 32bit indexes. However it fails to render.
I have also updated the

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC::ByteWidth
```

accordingly.

Any advice welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly do you think is the meaning of `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT` as an index buffer format? If you [check the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-iasetindexbuffer), you will find there are only two valid formats that `IASetIndexBuffer()` will accept. If your indices are `std::uint32_t` then the corresponding DXGI format to use would be `DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT`. Apart from that, I highly recommend to [use a debug context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps) and look at the debug output when debugging…

Comment: Many thanks, that worked. I incorrectly thought the R8G8B8A8 section is purely a size indication eg 8+8+8+8 = 32bits. But I was obviously wrong.

Comment: The one other thing to keep in mind is that 32-bit indices require Direct3D Hardware Feature Level 9.2 or better. Not a major requirement, but something to know. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels/) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ff471324#IA_Index_Buffer)